# slideDown effect() does not start on the right spot of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

The upper left button on hover slides down a div with sample description. The problem is that on sliding down it seems like the description comes out of the second button and merges with the first one, not just comes out of the first button. How can I solve that?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href = "styles.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" />
        <script src = "jquery-2.0.1.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
        <script src = "jquery-ui-1.10.3/jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery-ui.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
        <script src = "script.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
    </head>


    <body>
        <div id = "header">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>


        <div id = "buttons">
            <div class = "column_div">

                <div id = "button_div1" class = "button_div">
                    <img id = "text1" class = "button_pic" src = "http://s7.postimg.org/82pi8xcez/active_rus.png" />
                </div>

                <div id = "button_div2" class = "button_div">
                    <img id = "text2" class = "button_pic" src = "http://s7.postimg.org/82pi8xcez/active_rus.png" />
                </div>

            </div>


            <div class = "column_div">
                <div id = "button_div3" class = "button_div">
                    <img id = "text3" class = "button_pic" src = "http://s7.postimg.org/82pi8xcez/active_rus.png" />
                </div>

                <div id = "button_div4" class = "button_div">
                    <img id = "text4" class = "button_pic" src = "http://s7.postimg.org/82pi8xcez/active_rus.png" />
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class = "column_div">
                <div id = "button_div5" class = "button_div">
                    <img id = "text5" class = "button_pic" src = "http://s7.postimg.org/82pi8xcez/active_rus.png" />
                </div>

                <div id = "button_div6" class = "button_div">

                    <img id = "text6" class = "button_pic" src = "http://s7.postimg.org/82pi8xcez/active_rus.png" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**styles.css**

```
body
{
    background-color: black;
}


#header
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}


h1
{
    color: white;
}


#buttons
{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}


.column_div
{
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}


.button_div
{
    width: 280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.button_pic
{
    width: 280px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
}


#descr
{
    background-color: white;
    width: 280px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: -5px auto 5px auto;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
}


h3
{
    float: left;
    height:100px;
}
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $(document).on ("mouseenter", "#text1", function() {
        $("#descr").remove();
        $("#button_div1").append ("<div id = 'descr'></div>");
        $("#descr")
            .hide()
            .append ("<h3>Sample description</h3>")
            .slideDown ("slow");
    });


    $(document).on ("mouseleave", "#text1", function() {
        $("#descr").slideUp ("slow", function() {
                $(this).remove();
        });
    });


    $(document).on ("mouseenter", "#descr", function() {
        $("#descr").slideUp ("slow", function() {
                $(this).remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MesfB/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kenfly51/MesfB/8/)

The problem is the image itself, its `display` value is `inline` so you will see the extra space at the bottom, so just change this into `block` and adjust some `margin` of the parent div.

Answer (score 2):

Delete `margin: 5px auto 5px auto;` from #descr.
Like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MesfB/5/)

Comment: but then it won't come from the first button, it simply comes out of the second one

Comment: `vertical-align: top;` for image and bottom margin for `.button_div`